# "Choose between tracking…" disappeared

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, privileges

While visiting [my profile on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/58664/a-l?tab=topactivity), I clicked on the *Choose between tracking your next privilege and a tag badge* button and chose *Track a tag badge instead*. Now the button has disappeared:

> [image]

As you can see on the picture, I didn't posted any question or answer, so it seems that it was impossible to choose a tag badge and that broke the system.

Comment: Quick, ask a question or answer one!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest fix for this was to disable choosing a tracker when a user has no tag participation yet.

In your case, the privilege view should come back.  When you ask or answer a question, you'll be able to choose again.

This fix is being pushed out now.

Comment: That's fixed, you're really efficient! Thanks.

Comment: This has happened to me and asking or answering questions does not seem to help?

Comment: @RubyJunk on which site is this happening?

Comment: @JarrodDixon I fixed it, see my question, where Shadow Wizard helped me with some magic jQuery. The site it was happening on was Hardware Recommendations, but now is fixed.

Comment: @RubyJunk looking at [your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267876/next-privilege-tracker-gone) now... I think I see the issue.