# Choosing to track badge progress shows nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

If I decide to track badge progress instead of the next privilege:

[image]

I get to track nothing with no way to get back to the previous state:

[image]

(This is on [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/users/105/chrisf) as I initially thought that this was only available when you hit the "Trusted User" level).

It could be that there aren't any tag badges to track - which may be possible of course - but in that case please allow me to go back to tracking progress to the next level.

Unlike [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266137/choose-between-tracking-disappeared) I do have posts on Community Building, but I haven't posted anything since I flipped the option.

It may be significant that no tag badges have been awarded on [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze)

Comment: Looks like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266137/choose-between-tracking-disappeared, but that's [status-completed]. Hrm.

Comment: @NathanTuggy interesting. I do have answers on Community Building (but no questions) but I haven't posted in a while and certainly no since I selected that option.

Comment: @ChrisF same problem, but I certainly have more privileges to go. On hardware recs, I have a 120 rep and the same problem.

Comment: For a dirty but working work-around see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267879/152859).