# Can no longer toggle between tracking tag badges and tracking privileges?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, badge-progress

I just noticed that the gear icon on my profile that I used to be able to click to toggle between tracking my next privilege and my next tag badge has disappeared:[image]

(If I remember correctly, the gear used to be to the right of the progress bar in this picture.)

I've observed this on all the sites where I have accounts (namely, both Mathematics.SE and MathOverflow; on both sites, I am stuck tracking the next privilege).

I first noticed that it was gone when I reached the 10k privileges on Mathemathics.SE and then clicked "Track the next privilege" on my profile page there.  However, it is gone on both Mathematics.SE and MathOverflow (and I haven't recently reached a new privilege on MathOverflow).

Update: I can toggle back to tracking a tag badge using the fix mentioned in Shadow Wizard's comment below.  While tracking a tag badge, the gear to toggle back to tracking privileges is visible again, and I can use it to switch.  However, once I switch back to tracking privileges using it, it disappears again.

Comment: @PatrickHofman rolled back *to* the bug tag.

Comment: [This has been reported on MSO too](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308461/993547).

Comment: This appears to be side effect of fixing [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267876/next-privilege-tracker-gone). Until fixed, you can use the workaround in my answer, just replace the `/set-first-tracker/3` in the POST url to be `/set-first-tracker/2` and you'll have your next tag tracked. (Note to run it from the Ask Question page, not profile page, otherwise you'll get a 418 teapot error due to missing fkey)

Comment: Fixing this now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was completely my boneheaded fault by trying to only do a certain query if *reeaaally* necessary - well, it was really necessary after all :P

A fix will be pushed out soon.

Comment: Will it fix this case too - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267429/choosing-to-track-badge-progress-shows-nothing - or is this something else?

Comment: Yes, it will basically not show the "gear" any longer, as there are no tag badges yet on Community Building.  Not the best solution, I know, as it generates confusion.  Will ping our designer about something better.

Comment: I did wonder whether that was cause of the problem

Comment: Maybe show it and when clicking it show message explaining why it can't be changed? This will be consistent with many other things, e.g. voting.