# Next privilege tracker gone?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

When I look at my rep, there is no tracker saying my next privilege. However, this only happens on [my hardware recs profile](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/476/john-lee?tab=topactivity). On any other stack exchange sites, I see it, clear as day. Why is it gone? As you can see below: No rep tracker!

[image: No rep tracker]

Comment: This got nothing to do with reputation, it is part of the new profile page design which is used to track the next privilege, not reputation.

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh.

Comment: I also don't see it on your profile there, though it shows up for me in my own profile. Bug indeed, hope a dev will see this soon.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I do not think it is. I see the same phenomenon on [the OP’s profile](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/476/john-lee?tab=topactivity), where I should see the next privilege. I guess however, that it may have something to do with [hardwarerecs.se] entering public beta.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft the profile you linked to is my profile?

Comment: @John Lee: Yes, and in contrast to Shadow Wizard, I also see what you see.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft How interesting. I also noticed that [this](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/155/adam) profile has the same issue on hardware recs.

Comment: @John did you choose by any chance "Track a tag badge instead" at some point? According to [this open bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267429/choosing-to-track-badge-progress-shows-nothing), this indeed cause the whole thing to disappear. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard :| are you kidding me? I may have done that, I'm still a newbie, I didn't know clicking on things could be dangerous :(

Comment: Of course, nobody can know. That's why it's called a bug. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard lol I hope they can fix it soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might have found a workaround, until the bug is fixed. Brace yourself, it's awkward, but it might just work. :)

1. Go to the Ask Question page, e.g. https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask
2. Open your browser's dev console:

   - for Chrome, it's F12 ➔ Console
   - for Firefox, it's right-click ➔ Inspect Element ➔ Console
3. Type this into the console and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   $.post("https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/activity/set-first-tracker/3", {"fkey": $("#fkey").val()});
   ```

You should see "Object {readyState: 1}" response, and hopefully your privilege tracker will be back.

---

For those who wonder, this imitates going to the profile page and choosing "Track my next privilege", when the tracker is there. And luckily, it also works when it's gone.

Comment: ooook. Interesting =P

Comment: lol, jQuery is a magic fix. :D

Comment: oops, sorry for your lost edit @John I was in the middle of my own edit. Added now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8):

There was an issue where users could choose to track a tag badge, even if the newer site they were participating on had no tags that qualified for tag badges*.

This has been fixed - thanks!

<sup>* remember, a tag must have at least 100 questions tagged with it to be a candidate for tag badges.</sup>

Comment: [Possible side effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268269/can-no-longer-toggle-between-tracking-tag-badges-and-tracking-privileges)?

Comment: Yep, completely :(

Comment: So time for another bug hunting - good luck! :-)